# Как открыть ссылку в браузере через Java?

Tags: java

Нужно открыть заданную ссылку через основной браузер на Java.

Comment: я правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: да, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если ответ помог, то можете поставить галочку слева от верного ответа. см:[Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите открыть ссылку в браузере из вашего приложения в Desktop окружении, то можете воспользоваться классом `java.awt.Desktop`.

Данный класс позволяет Java запускать приложения, зарегистрированные в системе для обработки выбранных файлов или URI.

Данный класс поддерживает:

- запуск браузера по умолчанию
- запуск почтового клиента по умолчанию
- запуск приложения ассоциированного с определенным типом файла, для его обработки (например, дефолтный музыкальный проигрыватель для открытия mp3 или блокнот для открытия txt)

Открыть брайзер с его помощью можно примерно так:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://ru.stackoverflow.com"));
```

Каждая операция представляет собой тип действия, представленный классом `Desktop.Action`.
Для открытия ссылки нам необходимо действие `Desktop.Action.BROWSE`.

Во избежания непредвиденных ошибок необходимо:

- проверить поддержку Desktop окружения
  `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()`
- проверить поддержку необходимого действия
  `Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE))`

С проверкой поддержки вызов будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://ru.stackoverflow.com"));
}
```

И полноценный рабочий пример:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Документация: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html